# The Stable Set Conjecture

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, additive-combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics

A set $\mathcal S$ of positive integers is called *stable* if for every fixed positive integer $d$, the relation
$$n\in \mathcal S \iff dn\in \mathcal S$$
holds for almost all positive integers $n$. Typical examples of such sets are
$$\mathcal Q_\gamma =\{n : P(n)>n^\gamma\}$$
where $P(n)$ denotes the greatest prime factor of $n$ and $0<\gamma<1$.

The *lower asymptotic density* of a set $\mathcal A$ is defined by
$$\underline{d}(\mathcal A)=\liminf_{x\to \infty} \frac 1x \left\lvert \{n\le x : n\in \mathcal A\}\right\rvert$$
and upper density defined similarly using $\limsup$.

Hildebrand [1] proved that if a set $\mathcal A$ is stable and has positive lower density, then
$$\underline{d}\left (\mathcal A\cap \left (\mathcal A+1\right)\right) >0$$
implying the fact that for every $\epsilon>0$, there are infinitely many integers $n$ such that both $n$ and $n+1$ has a prime factor $>n^{1-\epsilon}$.

This leads us to the Stable Set Conjecture :-

> If a set $\mathcal A$ is stable and has positive lower density, then
> $$\underline{d}\left (\mathcal A\cap \left (\mathcal A+1\right)\cap \left (\mathcal A+2\right)\cdots \cap \left (\mathcal A+k\right)\right) >0$$
> for any $k\in \mathbb N$.

I want to know what progress have been made on this conjecture so far. Please use appropriate citations.

[1] *Hildebrand, Adolf*, [**On a conjecture of Balog**](https://doi.org/10.2307/2045835), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 95, 517-523 (1985). [ZBL0597.10056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0597.10056).

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.08544

Answer (score 12):

There is a subsequent 1989 paper by Hildebrand, "On integer sets containing strings of consecutive integers" which shows that the if the set satisfies $d(A)>\frac{k-2}{k-1}$ then the conjecture holds for that set and that choice of $k$. I'm not aware of any further progress on the general conjecture.

Comment: @SayanDutta As $k$ gets larger $(k-2)/(k-1)$ gets closer to 1, so one gets further from $1/2$ as the needed minimum.

Comment: Ah sorry, my brain wasn't braining (+1 though)

Comment: In my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.05096 with Teravainen (see Theorems 1.8-1.10) we can lower the density thresholds slightly, from $1 - \frac{1}{k-1}$ to $1 - \frac{1}{k-4/3+o(1)}$, assuming a Matomaki-Radziwill type equidistribution hypothesis on $A$.  Further progress may require resolving the Fourier uniformity conjecture (related to the Chowla and Sarnak conjectures), and seems difficult with current technology.

Answer (score 6):

Seems to have been disproven, for all $k > 1$: [A counterexample to Hildebrand's conjecture on stable sets](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.08544), Redmond McNamara.